# Error in playerview after adding IMA dependency in exoplayer

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I have implemented styledplayerview of exoplayer :-

```
     <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView    
            android:id="@+id/player_view"    
            android:layout_width="match_parent"    
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:resize_mode="fill"
            app:played_color="#A40A2F"
            app:scrubber_color="#A40A2F"
            app:show_subtitle_button="true"
 />
```

but after adding IMA ads dependency   ***implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-ima:2.14.0'***

, I am getting following error:-

```
error: cannot access AdViewProvider
        playerView.setControllerVisibilityListener(this);
                  ^
  class file for com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ads.AdsLoader$AdViewProvider not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just added 2 more dependencies i.e

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.14.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.14.0'
```